# Cannot append localStorage data to an existing div class

Tags: javascript, html, css, local-storage, visualization

Currently making a quick journal entry app in HTML, CSS, and JS. User inputs and submits text data along with the time and date. I'm trying to take that data from the localStorage to put inside an existing div class. Any advice?

This is the HTML code.

```
<div class="background-journal">
        <button class="button-journal" onclick="openPopup()" id="entrybtn">New Entry</button>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <button class="show-journal" onclick="recallEntries()" id="showbtn">View Previous Entries</button>
        <div class="journal-visual" id="data-viz">
    
        </div>
    <div id="popup" class="popup">
    <form id="form" class="form">
        <br>
        <label for="journal-entry">何を勉強していますか？</label><br><br>
        <textarea class="add-entry" id="journal-entry" rows="6" cols="150"></textarea><br>
        <button type="submit" onclick="submitJournalEntry()">Submit</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="closePopup()">Close</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

This is the CSS code.

```
.background-journal{
  position:absolute; 
  top: 35%; 
  left: 9.6%; 
  background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0); 
  z-index:1001;
  width: 80%;
  height: 600px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.button-journal {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: none;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 90%;
  height: 100px;
  left: 4.5%;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 3px 5px #888888;
}

.show-journal{
  background-color: #fff;
  border: none;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 90%;
  height: 100px;
  left: 4.5%;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 3px 5px #888888;
}

.journal-visual{
  background-color: #fff; 
  z-index:1003;
  width: 70%;
  height: 450px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
}

.button-popup-journal{
  position: relative;
}

.popup {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 3px 5px #000;
}

.popup form{
  margin: auto;
}

.add-entry{
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  position:inherit;
  left: 5%;
}

.background-journal label{
  color: white;
  opacity: 70%;
}
```

and this is the JS code.

```
    // Journal Function

  function openPopup() {
    document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("entrybtn").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("showbtn").style.display = "none";
  }
  
  function closePopup() {
    document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("entrybtn").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("showbtn").style.display = "block";
  }
  
  function submitJournalEntry() {
    var journalEntry = document.getElementById("journal-entry").value;

  var date = new Date();
  var timestamp = date.toString();

  localStorage.setItem(timestamp, journalEntry);
    
    closePopup();
  }

  function recallEntries() {
    document.getElementById("entrybtn").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("showbtn").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("data-viz").style.display = "block";
    var keys = Object.keys(localStorage);
  
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
      var key = keys[i];
      var journalEntry = localStorage.getItem(key);
      var viz = document.getElementById('data-viz');
      div.innerHTML = '<p><strong>' + key + '</strong>: ' + journalEntry + '</p>';
      document.body.appendChild(viz);
  }
  }
```

I was expecting the text to show up in the div class="journal-entry" id="data-viz" but nothing is there. Any ideas?

Comment: Where is the `div` variable (in `div.innerHTML`) defined? Is that meant to be `viz`?

Comment: Yup. Just caught it. Changed it though, now it only shows one text. If I enter more than one submission, it only shows the first one.

Comment: Well, setting the `innerHTML` overwrites what's there at the moment. Each time your loop runs it removes the previous text. You could use `+=` instead of `=` to add to, rather than overwrite the content.

Comment: Aaaaand that's the kicker. I still have a lot to learn about HTML. Thank you, kind stranger.